# Finding Gaps Between Employee Data 2D Array and Department Data 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays

Hey guys I'm working with a data set that has 14 columns (Department ID, Employee ID, and the months of the year) showing how many hours each employee worked for each month.

The function I am working with needs to print out the row for employees who record a zero value for a particular month when his/her department (as a whole) recorded a non-zero value (i.e. John in Marketing recorded zero hours for May when the department total was 500 hours so we print John's row).

I have two helper functions: `cost_center_sum(A)` which takes in the 2D array of data (organized as a list of lists) and finds the cumulative hours for each department as a list of lists. The second helper function, `compcols(row, A)`, matches the department ID of "row" with the appropriate row in the data set A and checks to see if the zero value in "row" for a particular month corresponds to a zero for the same month in the row matched in A.

I tried compiling these two functions into the function, `findgaps(A)`, which prints the employee information for an employee who records a zero for a month the department recorded a non-zero value.

Below is the code for the functions I described above:

```
def compcols(row, A):
for i in range(len(A)):
    if len(A[i]) < len(row):
        print row, (" - beware : line %d len(A[i]) %d < len(row) %d"
                    %(i, len(A[i]), len(row)))
    else:
        if row[0]==A[i][0]:
            for j in range(len(row)):
                if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:
                    print row
                    break


NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12
def cost_center_sum(A):
    dep = dict()
    for row in A:
        if row[0] not in dep:
            dep[row[0]] = [0.0 for x in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS)]
        for i in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS):
            dep[row[0]][i] += row[i+2]
    ret = list()
    for department in sorted(dep.iterkeys()):
        x = [department]
        x.extend(dep[department])
        ret.append(x)
    return ret

def findgaps(A):
    X=cost_center_sum(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            if A[i][j] < 0.00001:
                return compcols(A[i],X)
```

I have tested the other functions and they seem to do their job fairly well (there is a minor bug in `compcol` which prints out the same line several times), but when I use the `findgaps` function, it provides a completely incorrect output of only one employee row printed 80 times:

```
[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 76 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14
[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 77 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14
[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 78 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14
[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 79 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14
[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 80 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14
```

Answer (score 1):

`findgaps` will only ever `return` once; after the first call to `compcols`, the function is over:

```
def findgaps(A):
    X=cost_center_sum(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            if A[i][j] < 0.00001:
                return compcols(A[i],X) # only ever returns once
```

Instead, it should be something like:

```
def findgaps(A):
    X = cost_center_sum(A)
    for row in A:
        if any(month < 0.00001 for month in row[2:]):
            yield compcols(row, X)
```

This is a "generator" that will return multiple values. Note that you don't need the indices `i` and `j` - they only complicate the code, and you can see how much clearer it is when you iterate over the objects themselves.

Next, `compcols` is reporting "warnings" whether the first item matches or not. I think it should instead be:

```
def compcols(row, X):
    for dept_row in X:
        if row[0] == dept_row[0]:
            for emp_month, dep_month in zip(row[2:], dept_row[2:])
                if emp_month == 0 and dep_month != 0:
                    return row
    else:
        print "No match for department {0}.".format(row[0])
```